# How to use like query in cassandra CQL?

Tags: php, mysql, cassandra

I am a novice programmer to cassandra. I want to search records from cassandra database based on some text. For example I want to search records which are all contains "test". How can achieve this in cassandra.

Simply how to use mysql LIKE in cassandra ? Is there any other alternative for this ?

Answer (score 2):

LIKE isn't supported in Cassandra

The only way to do this efficiently is to use a full-text search engine like https://github.com/tjake/Solandra (Solr-on-cassandra)